# How to make an app that works in any computer in C++Builder 6?

Tags: c++builder-6

What can I do to make my application written in C++Builder 6 work on any computer? Currently it only works on my computer.

Comment: you probably need to install a redistributable on the other computer.

Comment: I assume that "any computer" is limited to "the same OS"?

Answer (score 0):

By default, C++Builder 6 projects are setup with Runtime Packages and Dynamic RTL both enabled. That will require you to distribute things like rtl6.bpl, vcl6.bpl, borlndmm.dll, etc alongside your EXE to other computers.

If you don't want to do that, you can disable those 2 options in the Project Options. That will cause the project to produce a self-contained EXE, which you will be able to distribute to other computers without the other BPL and DLL files (unless you use components that have their own external dependancies, which is a separate issue).